# dell wifi is installed but not working Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

Before I installed the Ubuntu i ran trying mode and installed the driver by Additional driver. It was working , but but after the installation it is not working any more.
This is the output of `lspci -nn | grep 0280`:

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

output of iwconfig:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

output of `rfkill list all`:

```
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Do you have a function key I.E. [Fn] + [F11] or similar that is disabling your wifi?

Comment: Yes there is the function key .... there is no change when I enable or disable the wifi with function key .... it was working fine in 12.04

Comment: any one please help !!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just formatted the whole system and installed the Ubuntu once again and it Additional driver worked and WiFi is working one again.